# Motif Search - Bash

Tags: regex, bash, shell, conditional-operator

I am trying to use "if" condition inside a for loop to check if the given motif is present in the fasta file and if Yes to print the header of the file.
When I executed this,

```
for f in *.fasta ; do
 if [[ cat $f | grep -q "GAEA" ]]; then
   echo $f
   grep "^>" $f | tr -d ">" "
 fi
done
```

I am getting an error: "conditional binary operator expected"

I also tried,

```
for f in *.fasta ; do
if [[ 'grep 'GAEA' $f' ]];then
   echo $f
   grep "^>" $f | tr -d ">" "
 fi
done
```

Both of which are not working. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Use `if grep -q 'GAEA'; then` (no need for `[[...]]`

Comment: Also the fix the missing quote in the `tr` command

Comment: from [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/) : `Use 'if cmd; then ..' to check exit code, or 'if [[ $(cmd) == .. ]]' to check output.`

Comment: Thanks, @oliv. The loop is not throwing any error now but running infinitely.

Comment: maybe is running infinitely because waiting input from stdin, use `grep -q "GAEA" <$f` or `grep -q 'GAEA' "$f"`

Comment: Thanks, @Nahuel It's working now.